# using default value in g:select tag in grails

Tags: grails

I am using g:select tag like this

```
<g:select id="ua_selectedResource" style="width:100px;font-size: 9px"  from='${resourcesList}' value="" optionKey="id" optionValue="resourceName"  noSelection="['null':'Select a Resource']">
</g:select>
```

resourceList is a list of resource objects (with fields id, resourcename...etc), I want the default selected value to be the resource which has id '1' . How do I set that condition in the value attribute?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to set the value of the g:select to the id you want to be selected.

```
<g:select id="ua_selectedResource" style="width:100px;font-size: 9px"  
  from='${resourcesList}' value="1" optionKey="id" optionValue="resourceName"  
  noSelection="['null':'Select a Resource']" />
```